# ssh in shell script, then execute commands after password

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm trying to write a simple shell script to execute commands on my server box via ssh.

I'm not trying to pass a password within the shell script, I'm just wondering how I can get it to run commands on that box after the password is entered.

So far, when I execute my script, nothing happens after I enter the password. Or, it executes when I kill the ssh process.

I'm sure it's really easy, but I've been searching for hours and nothing has come up on the net, probably because nobody else needs to ask that.

Is there some way to do this natively within the shell? Thanks!

Comment: The command line of `ssh` is something like this: `ssh user@host command`. The command is executed on the remote host after authentication. `man ssh` is your best friend.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: Thanks, I got it. basically, I tried everything but that. It was even simpler than I thought... I'm new to the shell as you can see

Answer (score -1):

Look if you want to ssh without prompting password then you need a key authentication rather password authentication.
Else try;

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname
```

And to execute command at remote;

```
ssh user@host 'command'
```

Comment: That was not the OPs question.

Comment: thanks man, i got it, and i'll definitely try key authentication another time!

Comment: @axiac I hope you didn't see 'Else try,' phrase

Comment: Any reason for negative vote? Please explain, so that I can improve?